# sonarlint is forcing to declare constant of a final class as protected

Tags: java, sonarlint

I have a final class with private constructor:

```
public final class Constants {
   public static final Date DEFAULT_DATE;

   static {
    // some code that creates localDate
    DEFAULT_DATE = localDate.toDate();
   }

   private Constants() {
   }
}
```

sonarlint issues a warning:

```
 Make DEFAULT_DATE protected
 reason: Mutable fields should not be "public static"
```

Declaring it protected does not make sense. The class is declared final - so no inheritance is possible. Secondly, I am using DEFAULT_DATE in other classes, so it has to be public.

Also, the constructor is declared private, so no object can be created.

Why sonarlint is forcing to make DEFAULT_DATE protected?

Comment: User of your code can invoke methods on Date object and change the state of the date. `final` keyword only prevents usage of `=` assignment but does not prevent the usage of `.` dot. `Constants.DEFAULT_DATE.setTime(204587433443L)` Your date is now changed. Hence You must avoid making it public and restrict its direct access as much as possible.

Comment: You have answers to your question. If there is something which is not clear or still remaining as un answered, let us know. If your query is answered you can accept one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

As other explained `java.util.Date` is a mutable, hence it is a bad design to provide it as a constant as it is really not.

@nits.kk gave a better solution to "Keep the long value of Date as a constant" and use let the caller convert the long value to the Date object.

```
public static final long DEFAULT_DATE = <long value representing the required date>;
```

Just an improvement on this and how I am using now in my code is to use `java.time.Instant` which is an immutable object

```
public static final Instant DEFAULT_DATE = Instant.parse("<ISO-formatted-date>");
```

This way I keep the intended Date object and there will be no more warning/error from the static checker.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the Date class is mutable, so if any object gets a reference to your Constants object they can change the dates value without you knowing. It would be better to make it private and provide a getter that returns a copy of the value.

Comment: The caller can still modify the value of the copy. How can I force the caller to use my constant? Also, there is a legacy code that is calling this constant as Constants.DEFAULT_DATE. Adding a getter would need to change all over and we might not have a control.

Comment: caller will modify the copy and not your object hence any new read will keep the intended value of date only. Each read is serviced by a new copy of your mutable object

Comment: Moreover having DEFAULT_DATE in constants as public is a bad design as it is not a Constant as its mutable, hence if you want to use it as a constant then return a copy through getter method. In getter, create a new Date object, copy the value from your original object and return the copy. Do it for each getter invokation.

Comment: IMHO this boils down to where that Constant class is used. If it's internal code that nobody outside your company compiles against, you're fine. If this class is part of an API, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I have already mentioned in my comments. I reiterate the points and add few new points below in a comprehensive way.

1. Having a public Date type reference and treating and assuming it as constant ( by declaring it with final static keywords) is a BAD design as its not a constant (Date is mutable).
2. Using `final` keyword prevents the re assignment i.e. you can not use `=` assignment operator again. But `final` keyword does not prevent `.` , dot operator. Using dot operator the state of the date object can be modified. 
   `Constants.DEFAULT_DATE.setTime(204587433443L)` Will modify your assumed constant date.
3. *Solution 1* :  You can make DEFAULT_DATE as private and can    create a getter method and when ever it is invoked, you can create a new Date object, copy the state of  DEFAULT_DATE and return the same. This way even if any modification is done it will be on the copied object and original object will remain as it is. For another read a fresh copy of the original object will be returned.
4. *Better solution 2* : Keep the long value of Date as a constant.  Let the caller of the code create the date object  using the constant long value. (You may also add a utility method somewhere in your code , may be a utility class if you have where you can take long as input parameter and return a date object after  creating the date object corresponding to the input long value.)

You are executing static analyses tools means you have the code. Even if its legacy code, refactor it. If its not a part controlled by you, you can request the team handling the code to refactor it. If its part of some third party library, then probably you can send mail to them and wait for their response, and also in case the library owner do not intend to correct this, then may be you should use another library as current one may have some similar other issues.

Comment: Agreed with sol 2. Just an improvement that I can use immutable Instant object instead of mutable Date object. This why I can be more specific that I am dealing with "dates" rather than returning a number as "long".

Comment: @Muzammil If answer worked for you then mark it as accepted. Whatever option you choose, you have to take care that you do not expose your mutable object outside your class.